# notepad++ Inverse Regex replace (all but string)

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, notepad++, inverse

I essentially wish to match every line that *DOES NOT* contain this string "Hello"

Example:

```
sdfsdoifdoskf
fdgokfdghodfkg
hello
fdojgohdfgjkdfg
gfobjobhkdfokgdfg
dofjkdsf hello dfgkdfogdfg
xcvmxhckvmxck
fogkdfhokg
hello
```

I attempted this Regex pattern : `^((?!hello).)*$`

No matches found.

Basically i want to remove every line that *does not* contain the string "hello" using notepad++

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/290247/how-to-delete-all-lines-in-notepad-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need

Answer (score 9):

`^((?!hello).)*$` works in Notepad++ 6. I wonder if it's better than this: `^(?!.*hello).*$`

Answer (score 0):

As [Karsten](https://superuser.com/users/7057/karsten) [suggested](https://superuser.com/questions/290247/delete-all-lines-in-notepad-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need/1318767#comment1735247_290247) in a comment, one can use the LineFilter2 plugin in Notepad++, which is straightforward to install and use.

[image]

To install:

[image]

To launch:

[image]