# RegEx to Exclude line using Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [notepad++ Inverse Regex replace (all but string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264391/notepad-inverse-regex-replace-all-but-string)

Let's say I have the following ...

```
http://whateverurl.com/is-not-wanted-but-it-is-here-anyway
http://icantbelieveibeenonthisallday.com/i-want-to-shoot-myself
http://hereiswhatireallywant.net/hey-there-sweet-thang
http://howsithangingloser.org/i-hope-someone-helps-you
http://heresanotherbeauty.net/that-i-want-to-be-all-up-in
```

I want to find only the lines that DON'T contain ".net/", so I can then replace it with nothing, hence delete.

I searched online and this site and found the **(?!xxx)** string, 
so I was trying to do the **(?!.net/)** 
but it seems that Notepad++ doesn't support that string 
or I may be using it wrong since I'm new to RegEx.

Can anyone tell me how to find a line that excludes a certain string of characters in Notepad++ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/8264391/1119381

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>As far as I can tell, Notepad++'s regex support doesn't let you actually capture the newline character. You are better off using this regex:</strike>

```
^.*\.net.*$
```

Replace it with nothing (now it is a blank line), then change the Search Mode to extended and replace `\r\n\r\n` with `\r\n` (or `\n\n` with `\n` if using Unix style line endings).

BoltClock pointed out that I am behind times, and that version 6 supports this. You can use this regex to find those lines and remove them:

```
^.*\.net.*(\r\n|$)
```

**EDIT**:

> I appreciate your response, but you misunderstood what I said. I'm trying to find lines that DO NOT CONTAIN the .net/ to delete them. Can it be done?

Whoops. If you want to match lines that *do not* have `.net` in them, use this expression:

```
^(?!.*?\.net/).*\r\n
```

Works in Notepad++ 6.

Comment: It does starting from version 6.0 :)

Comment: I appreciate your response, but you misunderstood what I said. 

I'm trying to find lines that DO NOT CONTAIN the .net/ to delete them.

Can it be done?

Thanks again!

Comment: @BoltClock I failz. Thanks. Updated response, and maybe now I'll read release notes.

Comment: Wow dude, I been on this all day and all I had to do was upgrade my version of Notepad++. Thank you so much for your help. It worked!

Comment: @Lost305 you may accept **vcsjones**'s answer if it worked for you. This would also encourage you to participate in stackoverflow activities more. Thanks