# Matching a line not containing a word in Notepad++

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, notepad++

I am trying to match the lines in following not input NOT containing "VelSign" (using Notepad++):

> #MARKER VelSign 457.45 50 kmh
>
> #MARKER IsBridge true
>
> #MARKER TrafficSign 45
>
> #MARKER TrafficLight 45 445 444 40

I am using the following regex:
`^#MARKER (?!.*VelSign).*$`

Doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Now that you have edited out the backslash, this pattern works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Did you try to use "Find All in Current Document"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [notepad++ Inverse Regex replace (all but string)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264391/notepad-inverse-regex-replace-all-but-string)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Make sure that you upgrade Notepad++ to version 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133989/1633117), as they changed quite a lot in the regex engine. Especially line breaks and lookarounds were a bit problematic in earlier versions.

Comment: sorry about the typo. My regex is : ^#MARKER (?!.*VelSign).*$

Comment: @MihaiGALOS that works for me. what is it matching for you? (or what is it not matching)

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. Notepad++ says: Cannot find the text "^#MARKER (?!.*VelSign).*$"

Comment: @MihaiGALOS have you activated regex mode and have you upgraded to the most recent version of Notepad++? Before version 6 there were some significant shortcomings of the regex engine. Also, is the `#` right at the beginning of your lines? If not, add in `\s*` between `^` and `#`.

Comment: The regex was good indeed! I upgraded before asking the question but it only upgraded to 5.9.2

Thank you for the reply. Please post another answer so I can validate it.

Answer (score 12):

Turn this:

```
^#MARKER (?!.\*VelSign).*$
```

Into this:

```
^#MARKER (?!.*VelSign).*$
```

You are escaping the `*` operator, which causes the match of a literal `*` instead of 0 or more `.`.

Also, make sure that you have checked the RegularExpression option (see the third radio button):

[image]

Comment: @MihaiGALOS Did you try to use "Find All in Current Document"?

Comment: The regex was ok. I upgraded to 5.9.2 before asking, it seems v6 got it matched... :) Thank you.