# (REGEX); Invert Selection,

Tags: html, regex, hyperlink, notepad++, jpeg

Notepad ++ (REGEX); Invert Selection,

The following 2 different codes, it works very nicely. :)
now I want to combine these two different code!

```
\bhttps?:[^)''"\s]+\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png)
```

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20126/regex-to-get-all-image-links

```
^((?!hello).)*$
```

[notepad++ Inverse Regex replace (all but string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264391/notepad-inverse-regex-replace-all-but-string)

Comment: Your question is very badly presented, It very hard to understand what you want, and what you tried so far?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to make your question readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Forward

Ensure you're using the latest version of notepad++, there where known problems using regex in notepad++ v5 and before which have been corrected in v6.

## Description

- Capture the src attribute value
- works with double quoted, single quoted, and non-quoted attribute values
- avoids tricky edge cases which normally trip up simple expressions

`<img(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`

[image]

## How To

From Notepad++

1. press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to enter the find and replace
   mode
2. Select the Regular Expression option
3. Select the ". matches newline" option
4. In the "Find what" field place the following regex
   `<img(?=\s|>)(?=(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*?\ssrc=(['"]?)(.*?)\1(?:\s|>))(?:[^>=]|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>`
5. Click <kbd>Find All</kbd>

## Regex Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/rpFMXppww2)

**Sample Text**

Note the first two image tags have some very difficult edge cases

```
<img onmouseover=' img = 10; src="NotYourImage.png" ; if (3 <img && src="NotYourImage.png" && 6>3) { funRotate(src) ; } ; ' src="ImageYouAreLookingFor.png">
<img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
<img src="./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m" class="flt" id="captcha" height="33" width="110"/>
```

**Matches**

Group 0 gets the entire image tag
Group 1 gets the quote used to surround the src attribute, and is used to ensure the correct closing quote is matched
Group 2 gets the src value, or if you use the alternate regex above, will receive just the rd query string

```
[0][0] = <img onmouseover=' img = 10; src="NotYourImage.png" ; if (3 <img && src="NotYourImage.png" && 6>3) { funRotate(src) ; } ; ' src="ImageYouAreLookingFor.png">
[0][1] = "
[0][2] = ImageYouAreLookingFor.png

[1][0] = <img onmouseover=' src="NotTheDroidsYouAreLookingFor.png" ; if (x > 3) { funRotate(src); } ' src="http://another.example/picture.png">
[1][1] = "
[1][2] = http://another.example/picture.png

[2][0] = <img src="./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m" class="flt" id="captcha" height="33" width="110"/>
[2][1] = "
[2][2] = ./CaptchaServlet?rd=htb54m
```