# Remove all numbers + symbols from line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad, regex-group

Is it possible to remove every line in a notepad++ Not Containing

```
a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m
n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z

A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M
N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y   Z

,   .   '
```

**Like that :**

[image]

**Remove Non-ascii**

```
.*[^\x00-\x7F]+.*
```

**Remove Numbers**

```
.*[0-9]+.*
```

---

**Text :**

```
example
example'
example,
example.


example123
éxample è
[example/+
example'/é,
example,*
exa'mple--
example@
example"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264391/notepad-inverse-regex-replace-all-but-string

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  , I want to remove all lines containing letters+numbers , I want just **letters** + **, ' .** in lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?![a-zA-Z,.']+$).+$\R?
```

The regex matches any non-empty line (`.+`) that does not only consist of ASCII letters, `,`, `.` or `'`. `\R?` at the end matches an optional line break.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?![a-zA-Z,.']+$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern is not matched: `[a-zA-Z,.']+` - 1 or more ASCII letters, comma, period or single quote up to the end of the line (`$`)
- `.+` - 1+ chars other than line break char
- `$` - end of a line
- `\R?` - an optional line break char (sequence)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can remove them like this:

Find what: `^.*[^a-zA-Z.,'].*$`
Replace with: ``

Explanation:

- `.*` for any text
- the negated character class `[^...]` for any unwanted character
- then again `.*` for more any text
- You need to wrap it into `^...$` to match the whole line

If you want to delete the linefeed characters, then you can use `\r?\n` instead of the `$` sign. I.e.: `^.*[^a-zA-Z.,'].*\r?\n`

Comment: Thanks Sir , for helping me ^^

Comment: In Notepad++, negated character classes match line breaks (unlike in Vim). Also, if you add `\r?\n` at the end, the last line at the end of the document that matches the criteria won't be removed.

Comment: So, then `^.*[^a-zA-Z.,'].*$\R?` must be better because the `$` after the negated character class prevents matching line breaks. Then the optional `\R` should make sure it can delete the last line too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace all this match

```
^.+?[^a-zA-Z,.'\r\n]+(.|\r?\n)
```